# Suppression State Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'IlmImfd.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, opencv3.2

I seem to have an error with the linking part even though my code compiled with no errors.

I set the property like this:
[image: I set the property like this - linked image]

I also added files required in the 
`Linker -> General -> Additional library directories`  and
`Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

It still gave me an error after that.

code:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "C:/Users/Downloads/opencv_contrib-master/opencv_contrib-master/modules/face/include/opencv2/face.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::face;
using namespace std;
```

(output) error line:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'IlmImfd.lib'    opencvTry
```

(output) when I try to redo the project with the same codes with the lib files included:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct 
cv::Ptr<class cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer> __cdecl 
cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer::create(int,double)" ( 
create@FisherFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@SA?AU?
$Ptr@VFisherFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@@3@HN@Z) referenced in function main    
opencvTry   C:\Users\151554F\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\In 
progress\Face recog\opencvTry\try.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl 
cv::face::FaceRecognizer::predict(class cv::_InputArray const &)const " (?
predict@FaceRecognizer@face@cv@@QEBAHAEBV_InputArray@3@@Z) referenced in 
function main   opencvTry   C:\Users\151554F\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\In progress\Face recog\opencvTry\try.obj  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably added the correct include directories, but you forgot to link the actual libraries.

Under `Configuration Properties` - `Linker` - `General` - `Additional Library Directories` you need to add the following:
`$(OPENCV_DIR)\staticlib;`

With `OPENCV_DIR` pointing to your build folder.
For example: `E:\opencv\build\x86\vc12`.

After you've done that, you also need to add the lines below here under `Common Properties` - `Linker` - `Input` - `Additional Dependencies`

```
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libpngd.lib
libjpegd.lib
libtiffd.lib
libwebpd.lib
opencv_calib3d300d.lib
opencv_core300d.lib
opencv_features2d300d.lib
opencv_flann300d.lib
opencv_hal300d.lib
opencv_highgui300d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib
opencv_imgproc300d.lib
opencv_ml300d.lib
opencv_objdetect300d.lib
opencv_photo300d.lib
opencv_shape300d.lib
opencv_stitching300d.lib
opencv_superres300d.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
opencv_video300d.lib
opencv_videoio300d.lib
opencv_videostab300d.lib
zlibd.lib
ippicvmt.lib
comctl32.lib
vfw32.lib
```

You only need to add the ones you need, but there's no negative side at adding them all. Then, you're sure you didn't forget anything.

Comment: I saw the same solution in other questions too and used it before, and i have tried it even before asking this question. But it does not seem to be working for me. 
Every time i try to add something new to 

  `Linker -Input -Additional Dependencies`
 
whatever that is at the top will come out as an error saying that the file cannot be opened.

Comment: I have also tried to redo the project and the output is shown in the above which i have edited. I feel stuck right now as i don't really know what causes all these.